# no funciona el css

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo un pequeño formulario que me funciona bien, pero los pocos estilos que le he puesto no me funcionan. He probado a ponerlos con la etiqueta style dentro del head y a crear una hoja de estilos y llamarla desde la página del formulario. Este es el código de la hoja de estilos styles.css:

```
form{
    width:250px;
}
form>div>span{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
form input{
    width:150px;
}
form>div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Y este es el código del formulario prestamo.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["interes"])){
        $_POST["interes"]=str_replace(",",".",$_POST["interes"]);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>cálculo de hipotecas/préstamos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cálculo de hipotecas/préstamos</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
            <div>
                <span>Importe:</span>
                <span><input type="text" name="importe" maxlength=9 value="<?php //echo $_POST["importe"]; ?>"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Años:</span>
                <span><input type="text" name="anos" maxlength=2 value="<?php //echo $_POST["anos"]; ?>"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Interés:</span>
                <span><input type="text" name="interes" maxlength=9 value="<?php //echo $_POST["interes"]; ?>"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><input type="submit" name="calcular" value="Calcular"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["calcular"])){
        if($_POST["importe"]&&$_POST["anos"]&&$_POST["interes"]){
            $deuda=$_POST["importe"];
            $anos=$_POST["anos"];
            $interes=$_POST["interes"];
            $interes=($interes/100)/12;
            $m=($deuda*$interes*(pow((1+$interes),($anos*12))))/((pow((1+$interes),($anos*12)))-1);
            echo "<div>Capital Inicial: ".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")." €";
            echo "<br>Cuota a pagar mensualmente: ".number_format($m,2,",",".")." €</div>";
    ?>
        <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <th>Mes</th>
                <th>Intereses</th>
                <th>Amortización</th>
                <th>Capital Pendiente</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $totalint=0;
            for($i=1;$i<=$anos*12;$i++){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align=right>".$i."</td>";
                $totalint=$totalint+($deuda*$interes);
                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda*$interes,2,",",".")."</td>";
                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($m-($deuda*$interes),2,",",".")."</td>";
                $deuda=$deuda-($m-($deuda*$interes));
                if($deuda<0){
                    echo "<td align=right>0</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")."</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <p>Pago total de intereses: <?php echo number_format($totalint,2,",",".")?> €.</p>
    <?php } } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

He revisado el código del archivo styles.css y no encuentro ningún error. ¿Podría poner en cada elemento su correspondiente etiqueta style con sus comandos? Hasta ahora cualquier trabajo me había funcionado de las dos maneras.

Comment: ¿La hoja de estilos está en la misma carpeta que el archivo del formulario? Puede que no la encuentre por eso. Por otra parte, podrías poner en cada elemento una etiqueta `style` y su css dentro, pero no es recomendable, a la hora de mantener el código esto lo haría muy difícil y podrías tener problemas con otros css más adelante, es mejor hacerlo como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: si, están juntos los dos

Comment: Si lo pones el en `head` directamente ¿tampoco te funciona? Por descartar que estén siendo machacados por otros estilos y comprobar si te está cogiendo o no la hoja de estilos. (También puedes usar el inspector para comprobar si el archivo se está leyendo o si otros estilos están machando estos)

Comment: No esta tomando ningun estilo o solo esos? proba ponerle color de fondo al body y ver si aplica.... por otro lado no uses `form>div>span` simplemente usa `form div span` son los `>` no son necesarios en este caso

Comment: refresca la cache, ctrl+f5  o ctrl y click al reload del navegador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar las comillas dobles por unas simples en la etiqueta *form*, las comillas anidadas no las digiere muy bien

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' method="POST">
```

el codigo te quedaria asi:

```css
form{
    width:250px;
}
form>div>span{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
form input{
    width:150px;
}
form>div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["interes"])){
        $_POST["interes"]=str_replace(",",".",$_POST["interes"]);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>cálculo de hipotecas/préstamos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles5.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Cálculo de hipotecas/préstamos</h1>
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' method="POST">
        <div>
            <span>Importe:</span>
            <span><input type="text" name="importe" maxlength=9 value='<?php //echo $_POST["importe"]; ?>'></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Años:</span>
            <span><input type="text" name="anos" maxlength=2 value='<?php //echo $_POST["anos"]; ?>'></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Interés:</span>
            <span><input type="text" name="interes" maxlength=9 value='<?php //echo $_POST["interes"]; ?'></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><input type="submit" name="calcular" value="Calcular"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["calcular"])){
        if($_POST["importe"]&&$_POST["anos"]&&$_POST["interes"]){
            $deuda=$_POST["importe"];
            $anos=$_POST["anos"];
            $interes=$_POST["interes"];
            $interes=($interes/100)/12;
            $m=($deuda*$interes*(pow((1+$interes),($anos*12))))/((pow((1+$interes),($anos*12)))-1);
            echo "<div>Capital Inicial: ".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")." €";
            echo "<br>Cuota a pagar mensualmente: ".number_format($m,2,",",".")." €</div>";
    ?>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
        <tr>
            <th>Mes</th>
            <th>Intereses</th>
            <th>Amortización</th>
            <th>Capital Pendiente</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $totalint=0;
            for($i=1;$i<=$anos*12;$i++){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align=right>".$i."</td>";
                $totalint=$totalint+($deuda*$interes);
                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda*$interes,2,",",".")."</td>";
                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($m-($deuda*$interes),2,",",".")."</td>";
                $deuda=$deuda-($m-($deuda*$interes));
                if($deuda<0){
                    echo "<td align=right>0</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")."</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <p>Pago total de intereses: <?php echo number_format($totalint,2,",",".")?> €.</p>
    <?php } } ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos